# Socket closing not throwing IOException

Tags: java, sockets, client-server

I'm writing a basic Server-client program in Java and I'm trying to handle the case where the client terminates unexpectedly.

```
public void run() {
    while(alive) {
        try {
            // socketIn is a BufferedReader wrapped around the socket's InputStream.
            String input = socketIn.readLine();
            if(input == null)
                continue;
            String response = processInput(input);
            // socketOut is a PrintWriter wrapped around the socket's OutputStream.
            if(response != null) {
                socketOut.println(response);
                socketOut.flush();
            }
        } catch(IOException e) {
            System.out.println("TRACE 1");
            alive = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("TRACE 2");
}
```

But when I kill the client, the loop keeps going and neither TRACE is printed out. I'm assuming that when a socket is closed from the other end and I am trying to read from it, it will throw an IOException.

Was this a bad assumption? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Consider using connection timeouts and also look out for SocketExceptions.

Comment: Connection timeout is a good idea, and I think SocketException is a subclass of IOException.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) will return `null` at end of stream, which is what happens when the remote end closes the connection normally. You are attempting to `continue` on this condition, which will loop forever.  `IOException` will be thrown if the connection is broken abnormally.

Comment: We usually read from remote socket as follows: String msg = null; while ((msg = s.readLine()) != null) { //do stuff on the msg read ... }
//the socket has been closed from remote end.